# Create new column with time difference (Pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have columns start_time and end_time in a csv dataset with the time being in the format HH:MM (the datatype is type string since its from a csv). I want to use panadas (or anything realistically) to get the time delta between the two columns and put it in a new column called diff_minutes. To do this I tried the following,

```
dataset['diff_minutes'] = dataset['end_time'] - dataset['start_time']
dataset['diff_minutes']= dataset['diff_minutes']/np.timedelta64(1,'m')
```

But I got the following error, `ValueError: hour must be in 0..23`. I checked my dataset (it's big) and it turns out I have some hours that go above 23. For example, start_time : 25:58, end_time : 29 :20. Is there another method to get the time delta for values larger that 23?

Here's example data :

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = '''\
start_time,end_time
25:58,29:20
25:30,25:30
02:07,03:11
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

Which looks as:

```
  start_time end_time
0      25:58    29:20
1      25:30    25:30
2      02:07    03:11
```

Desired output

```
| start_time | end_time | diff_minutes
______________________________________
| 25:58      | 29:20    | 202
| 25:30      | 25:30    | 0
| 02:07      | 03:11    | 64
```

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert columns to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and if necessary also to strings:

```
dataset['diff_minutes'] = (pd.to_timedelta(dataset['end_time'].astype(str) + ':00') -
                           pd.to_timedelta(dataset['start_time'].astype(str) + ':00' ))
dataset['diff_minutes']= dataset['diff_minutes']/np.timedelta64(1,'m')
print (dataset)
  start_time end_time  diff_minutes
0      25:58    29:20         202.0
1      25:30    25:30           0.0
2      02:07    03:11          64.0
```

Comment: much appreciated.  Especially for a response sooo fast that stack wont let me mark it as correct for 3 more minutes lmao.